# Problemas De Herencia Multiple Python

Tags: python

estoy haciendo un trabajo de una clase de un curso que estoy tomando de python, y resulta que cree 4 archivos, en los que ocupe 2 para hacer las clases padres, y en un tercer archivo hice la clase hija con el metodo que queria ejecutar, y en le ultimo archivo importe todos los modulos correctamente pero a la hora de ejecutar me dice que no se encuentra el nombre del modulo que elegi. Inserto codigo de cada archivo para que se entienda mejor. Saludos gente.[image: Error que me aparece]

Codigo del archivo Figura Geometrica:

```
class FiguraGeometrica:
def __init__(self, alto,ancho):
    self.alto = alto
    self.ancho = ancho
```

Codigo del Archivo Color:

```
class Color:
def __init__(self,color):
    self.color = color
```

Codigo Del Archivo Cuadrado

```
from Heredados.FiguraGeometrica import FiguraGeometrica
from Heredados.Color import Color
class Cuadrado(FiguraGeometrica, Color):
    def __init__(self,lado,color):
        FiguraGeometrica.__init__(self, lado,lado)
        Color.__init__(self, color)
    
    def area(self):
        return self.alto * self.ancho
```

Comment: No es necesario que pongas el nombre de la carpeta si es que se encuentran en la misma ruta

Comment: Para que el código en `testFiguraGeometrica.py` te funcione, ese script debería estar en una carpeta un nivel superior, y los import en `Cuadrado.py` deberían ser relativos (`from .Color import Color` por ejemplo), y la carpeta `Heredados` debería tener un `__init__.py` vacío para marcar que esa carpeta es un "paquete" (conjunto de módulos)

Comment: Es que seguia sin funcionarme la unica forma fue agregar todo a un mismo archivo, lo probe de muchas maneras pero al parecer esta fue la unica que encontre que funcionaba, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

No hay problema con apuntar a la clase desde la raíz. Es lo mismo que yo haría.

Simplemente añade el archivo `__init__.py` vacío tanto en la raíz como en la carpeta `Heredados`. Eso permitirá a Python interpretar la estructura del código correctamente, **aun en Python 3**.

Chequea esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48804718/4710386